# Triggering an Output Event in an Input setter in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an angular 2 component and I want to have it two way data bound. Is it fine if I emit an event inside of a setter that is marked as an Input?

```
export class TimeDurationComponent {

  private _start: string;

  constructor() {  }

  @Output() startChange : EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();

  @Input()
  set start(value: string) {
    this._start = value;
    this.startChange.emit(value);
  }

}
```

or does this cause a problem? Because I see it this way:

```
<time-duration ([start])="block.start"></time-duration>
```

Does this now cause the change to be thrown forth and back? or does the change detection pick this up and makes sure it only happens once?

Comment: `<time-duration ([start])="block.start"></time-duration>` is invalid. It's called banana-in-a-box for a reason ;-) It should be `<time-duration [(start)]="block.start"></time-duration>`

Comment: That doesn't seem to provide any value. `start` is only set when `block.start` changes. If you emit `startChange` you will only update `block.start` with the value it already has. So what's the point?